# Python Pandas create 5 excel files from 1 table based on date

Tags: python, pandas, loops, date, export-to-excel

The dates are stored as datetime. I don't want to hard code the dates. I want the script to look for columns with the same date, group them together and export to a file with the date in the filename.

```
    Account  |  datestart   |   Charge  |
   ----------+--------------+-----------+
    123A     |  2019-03-14  |   7299    |
    5866A    |  2019-03-14  |   4000    | 
    12321A   |  2019-03-14  |   5000    |
    312332A  |  2019-03-13  |   5000    |
    586A     |  2019-03-13  |   4000    |
    967567A  |  2019-03-13  |   5167.66 |
    3437A    |  2019-03-12  |   9187.2  |
    956734A  |  2019-03-12  |   4482    |
    36736A   |  2019-03-11  |   4101    |
    3567356A |  2019-03-10  |   4007.85 |
    9467A    |  2019-03-10  |   5097.18 |
```

The script should export to 5 files. Each of the files would only include data with the specific date.

For Example the first file should look like

```
    Account  |  datestart   |   Charge  |
   ----------+--------------+-----------+
    123A     |  2019-03-14  |   7299    |
    5866A    |  2019-03-14  |   4000    | 
    12321A   |  2019-03-14  |   5000    |
```

second file should look like

```
    Account  |  datestart   |   Charge  |
   ----------+--------------+-----------+
    312332A  |  2019-03-13  |   5000    |
    586A     |  2019-03-13  |   4000    |
    967567A  |  2019-03-13  |   5167.66 |
```

The first file should be saved as file_031419 and the second should be file_031319. The data I will be looking at will have a variable of dates so the file names should be dynamic based on the dates in the file.

Here is some of the code I tried

```
filedates = list(none['datestart'].unique())

for date in filedates: 
   filename = 'File_'+list(set(pd.to_datetime(none.loc[idx, 'datestart']).dt.strftime('%m%d%y')))[0]+'.xlsx'
   none.loc[idx, 'datestart'].to_excel(filename)
```

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried

Comment: With the code I just added i'm only getting one file with all the data in it.

Comment: 1) do you really not have the code under your "for" statement indented?

Comment: 2) what is the idx = none.datestart == date supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below:

```
for i , g in df.groupby('datestart'):
    g.to_csv('C:\\path\\'+'file_'+ \
         g.datestart.dt.strftime('%y%m%d').astype(str).iloc[0] +'.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not much different from anky_91 but the filename is the same asked by the OP and it's maybe easier to understand given that once one work on the small function `save_group` it's very flexible

First we reproduce your very same dataset

```
import pandas as pd


txt = """123A     |  2019-03-14  |   7299    |
    5866A    |  2019-03-14  |   4000    | 
    12321A   |  2019-03-14  |   5000    |
    312332A  |  2019-03-13  |   5000    |
    586A     |  2019-03-13  |   4000    |
    967567A  |  2019-03-13  |   5167.66 |
    3437A    |  2019-03-12  |   9187.2  |
    956734A  |  2019-03-12  |   4482    |
    36736A   |  2019-03-11  |   4101    |
    3567356A |  2019-03-10  |   4007.85 |
    9467A    |  2019-03-10  |   5097.18 |"""

txt = txt.split("\n")
txt = [t.split("|")[:-1] for t in txt]

df = pd.DataFrame(txt, columns=["Account", "datestart", "Charge"] )
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str.rstrip().str.lstrip()

df["datestart"] = df["datestart"].astype("M8[us]")
```

Then for each group you want to save as csv file

```
def save_group(grp):
    fn = grp["datestart"].dt.strftime('%m%d%y').astype(str).iloc[0]
    fn = "".join(["file_",fn, ".csv"])
    grp.to_csv(fn, index=False)
```

To use it for every group you can just use `apply`

```
df.groupby("datestart").apply(lambda x: save_group(x))
```